# Table wrapping in tables not working

Tags: tables, wrap

I am having a problem with text wrapping in a long table.

Here is a copy of my table:

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{l|b{2in}b{3in} b{2in}} 
    %\centering
        %\begin{tabular}{llll}

Author and Year & Methods & Conformers found & Conclusion\\
\hline
\\
\citet{vishveshwara_77}&Single-point energy calculations at HF/4-31G of glycine rotamers generated at 60? intervals about C, C׃, and C bonds & Ip, IIp, IIIp&The lowest energy structure is Ip, giving energy order as Ip<IIp<IIIp\\  
%\end{tabular}
 \end{longtable}
```

I have tried many things but the second colon overruns the page. I have tried the rotating, sideways and supertable environment but none works. I am starting to think it is an incompatibility with some of the packages I am using because when I create a new file and past just the table it seems to work well.
Here is a copy of my main file

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt, twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.2in, vmargin=1.2in]{geometry}
%\linespread{1.2}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{url,parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[update,prepend]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[hang,small]{caption}%samllcaptions
\setlength{\captionmargin}{25pt}
\usepackage{verbatim}%
\pagestyle{headings} 
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{subfig}% for placing 2 figures on same line
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
% some useful packages
\usepackage{lscape}%for landscape
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage{setspace}% line spacing
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}%chemical symbols
%\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}%pdf bookmarks
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref} %hyperref
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[square, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{s}{}{;}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}% textscriping
\usepackage{soul}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the `pdfsync` package; if you *really* need to use this package, try loading it using the `novbox` option:

```
\usepackage[novbox]{pdfsync}
```

As a side note, some suggestions: 1) avoid using underscores in the argument of `\cite` commands.a 2) Avoid loading the same package more than once (I see that you load `graphicx` twice in the preamble). 3) There's no need to declare the `pdftex` driver for `graphicx`.

Comment: Thanks so very much. You are a life saver. I wondering why I hadn't asked 3 days ago. Thanks again and your suggestions are well noted of.